# How to identify actual day of week that markets end on?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, powerbi-desktop, stock

As of Dec 30, 2021 ----
I did figure this out.  New to Python, so this is not optimized or the most elegant, but it does return just the day that ends any market week.  Because of how I specify the start and end dates, the dataframe always starts with a Monday, and ends with the last market day.  Basically, it looks at each date in consecutive rows, assigns the difference in days to a new column.  Each row will return a -1, except for the last day of the market week.  The very last row of all data also returns a "NaN", which I had to deal with.  I then delete just the rows with -1 in the Days column.  Thank you for the feedback....here is the rest of the code that does the work, which follows the code I previously supplied.

```
data['Date']  = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])
data['Days_from_date'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(data['Date']).day

data['Days'] = data['Days_from_date'] - data['Days_from_date'].shift(-1)
data=data.replace(np.nan,-1)
data["Days"]=data["Days"].astype(int)

data = data[data['Days'] != -1]
data = data[data['Days'].ne(-1)]
```

This is the previous post.....

I currently have python code that gets historical market info for various ETF tickers over a set period of time (currently 50 days).  I run this code through Power BI.  When I get done testing, I will be getting approximately 40 weeks of data for 60-ish ETFs. Current code is copied below.

I would like to minimize the amount of data returned to *just* the CLOSE data generated on the last market day of each week.  Usually this is Friday, but sometimes it can be Thursday, and I think possibly Wednesday.

I am coming up short on how to identify each week's last market day and then pulling in just that data into a dataframe.  Alternatively, I suppose it could pull in all data, and then drop the unwanted rows - I'm not sure which would be a better solution, and, in any case, I can't figure out how to do it!

Current code here, using Python 3.10 and Visual Studio Code for testing....

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta

enddate = date.today()
startdate = enddate - timedelta(days=50)

tickerStrings = ['VUG', 'VV', 'MGC', 'MGK', 'VOO', 'VXF', 'VBK', 'VB']

df_list = list()
for ticker in tickerStrings:
   data = yf.download(ticker, start=startdate, group_by="Ticker")
   data['Ticker'] = ticker  
   df_list.append(data)

data = pd.concat(df_list)
data = data.drop(columns=["Adj Close", "High", "Low", "Open", "Volume"])
data = data.reset_index()
```

Comment: Isn't this a hopeless task?  Holidays do not always occur on Fridays, and the holidays vary for different markets.  I'm not sure this is knowable in the general case.

Comment: Unless you can determine what the rules are that determine what  the last day of a given week is, there's little hope of implementing it programmatically. Perhaps there some online source of the information you could poll.

Comment: If I add the week number from the date data, and then group the week number and get the last row, won't it always be the last day that I am open? Also, if you use the list to get the closing price, you can save time by getting only the closing price. `data = yf.download(ticker, start=startdate, group_by="Ticker")['Close']`

Comment: R-beginners, thank you for the idea and code to just grab Close data from the beginning.  Simple and elegant.  I will rework my code with this idea.   As for the week number and grouping idea, conceptually sounds like it could work….could you share some code ideas?   I had thought of using datediff somehow to detect when the date skips by more than a day (as would occur between whatever day is the week closing day and the next week’s opening day), somehow grab that close day and delete or disregard all others.  Being a total python newbie, it’s escaping me.

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, I think you can get the desired data by getting the week number from the date data, grouping it and getting the last row. For example, if Friday is a holiday, I considered Thursday to be the last data of the week number.

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta

enddate = date.today()
startdate = enddate - timedelta(days=50)

tickerStrings = ['VUG', 'VV', 'MGC', 'MGK', 'VOO', 'VXF', 'VBK', 'VB']

df = pd.DataFrame()
for ticker in tickerStrings:
    data = yf.download(ticker, start=startdate, progress=False)['Close'].to_frame('Close')
    data['Ticker'] = ticker  
    df = df.append(data)

df.reset_index(inplace=True)

df['week_no'] = df['Date'].dt.isocalendar().week
data = df.groupby(['Ticker','week_no']).tail(1).sort_values('Date', ascending=True)
```

Comment: If trading day calendar data is available as mentioned in the comments, use it. If not, it is possible to get it from the web, but it is a bit cumbersome. If you find my answer helpful, please click the check mark in the answer to accept the answer.